# Arc length is equal to a distance?

Tags: geometry

This figure is drawn without taking care of values. It's a guess where $\Gamma_1$ is a flat line while $\Gamma_2$ is the dotted grey arc with opening angle $2\theta$.

I was wondering what is the interpretation if we get the result:
\begin{equation}
h_2 = R_2(2 \theta)
\end{equation}
The strange in this that $R_2(2 \theta)$ is the same of the arc length $l=\int_{\Gamma_2}ds=R_2(2\theta)$. $h_2$ as you see starts at the point of intersection of dotted arc and black line. Do that make sense? or unacceptable result!

Comment: I don't understand what is the reason of parentheses in $h_2=R_2(2\theta)$, maybe in context $(2\theta)=\sin (2\theta)$?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu I assumed that the parentheses denoted multiplication, especially since the OP said that the arc length is the same as $R_2 (2\theta)$.

Comment: Result $h_2=2 R_2 \theta$ is incorrect, and result $l=2 R_2 \theta$ is correct. I supposed that the result $h_2=R_2(2\theta)$ was not obtained by OP, and was taken from some book, where parentheses can mean something unusual. I believe OP should give information about origin of result $h_2=R_2(2\theta)$.

Comment: @Aly Please include a rough sketch.

Answer (score 1):

The result is impossible for $0 < \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$.

As correctly noted, $h_2 \neq \Gamma_2 = R_2 \cdot 2\theta$ since $\Gamma_2$ takes a longer path to traverse the same distance as $h_2$.